# How to bind one singleton instance in ninject to multiple bind methods

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Using MVVM framework alongside Ninject, I have different concrete ViewModel classes all bound to an IViewModel interface. My issue is wanting some flexibility in how to determine which ViewModel is injected into a View. I want to be able to use the `Named(string)`attribute, `ConstraintAttribute`, or basic `Attribute` to determine the proper ViewModel

Or in other words, I want all of these to return a singleton AlphaViewModel instance:

```
Bind<IViewModel>().To<AlphaViewModel>().WhenTargetHas<AlphaAttribute>();
Bind<IViewModel>().To<AlphaViewModel>().WhenMemberHas<AlphaAttribute>();
Bind<IViewModel>().To<AlphaViewModel>().WhenClassHas<AlphaAttribute>();

Bind<IViewModel>().To<AlphaViewModel>().Named("Alpha");

Bind<IViewModel>().To<AlphaViewModel>().WhenInjectedInto<AlphaView>();
```

I've tried

```
A) Bind<IViewModel>().To<AlphaViewModel>().WhenInjectedInto<AlphaView>().InSingletonScope().Named("Alpha");
B) Bind<IViewModel>().To<AlphaViewModel>().WhenClassHas<AlphaAttribute>().InSingletonScope.Named("Alpha");
```

and similar combinations, but it seems to compound the requirements.

---

**A** will only have the correct injection if its setup like:

```
public partial class AlphaView : Window
{
    public AlphaView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public AlphaView([Named("Alpha")]IViewModel viewModel) : this()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**B** has a bit more leeway in that the View can be named something else, but it still requires both parameters to inject the ViewModel:

```
[AlphaAttribute]
public partial class BravoView : Window
{
    public BravoView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public BravoView([Named("Alpha")]IViewModel viewModel) : this()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

---

When what I want is to be able to inject the singleton AlphaViewModel using any one of the Attributes or Names such that all 3 instances can be used and point to the same ViewModel.

```
[AlphaAttribute]
public partial class CharlieView : Window
{
    public CharlieView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public CharlieView(IViewModel viewModel) : this()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}

public partial class CharlieView : Window
{
    public CharlieView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public CharlieView([Named("Alpha")]IViewModel viewModel) : this()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}

public partial class CharlieView : Window
{
    public CharlieView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    [AlphaAttribute]
    public IViewModel AlphaVM { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by having a single singleton binding for `AlphaViewModel`

```
Bind<AlphaViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

And n bindings "redirecting" the request to `AlphaViewModel`, like:

```
Bind<IViewModel>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<AlphaViewModel>())
    .WhenTargetHas<AlphaAttribute>();

...

Bind<IViewModel>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<AlphaViewModel>())
    .Named("Alpha");
```